# Auto height em iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tenho um iframe e preciso que a altura dele seja automática de acordo com o conteúdo que tem dentro dele. Como posso fazer isso? Sem jquery de preferência.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Infelizmente, não tem como deixar o iframe com altura automática de acordo com o conteúdo.

A única forma de resolver o problema é você implementar um Javascript dentro do iframe que mande a altura do body (de dentro do iframe) para fora do iframe via postMessage. Recebendo a altura, você redimensiona o iframe.

No link abaixo tem uma explicação de como fazer isso:

http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/iframes/postmessage/height/

Answer (score 0):

Cria uma classe e atribui a propriedade 'height:auto', caso queria limitar um tamanho máximo pode usar max-height:''.

Html

`<iframe class="frame"></iframe>`

Css

```
.frame{height:auto;max-heignt:100px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa setar nas tag body e html valor da altura: 100%, segue exemplo:

```css
body, html {
  height:100%;
}

iframe {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background:cyan;
}
```

```html
<iframe></iframe
```